# is it necessary to put 0 before the dot in RDF FLOAT type?

Tags: sparql, rdf, owl, ontology, protege

I am using a tool trying to generate triples.

I generate this triple:

```
<http://rs#Rating29728> <rs#ratesBy> ".2"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float> .
```

Is `.2` a correct float value, or should it be `0.2`?

In order to try that, I created a literal value in Protege, put the value as `0.2`. Then I closed Protege, edited the ontology manually, and changed `0.2` to `.2`. I opened it in Protege again, but Protege made it `0.2`, so i thought that `0.2` is the correct one, not `.2`, and Protege already prepared for such values.

what do you think please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is a legal xsd float isn't a matter of opinion; all we have to do is check the spec.

> #### [3.2.4 float](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#float)
>
> float values have a lexical representation consisting of a mantissa followed, optionally, by the character "E" or "e", followed by an exponent. The exponent ·must· be an integer. The mantissa must be a decimal number. **The representations for exponent and mantissa must follow the lexical rules for integer and decimal.** If the "E" or "e" and the following exponent are omitted, an exponent value of 0 is assumed.

So the question becomes whether decimal requires a leading zero.

> #### [3.2.3 decimal](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#decimal)
>
> decimal has a lexical representation consisting of a finite-length sequence of decimal digits (#x30-#x39) separated by a period as a decimal indicator.

Now, I'd say that no leading digits is a zero length sequence of digits, which is definitely a finite length sequence of digits, so `.2` would be fine.  The spec also defines a *canonical representation*, and it sounds like protégé might normalize to it:

> The canonical representation for decimal is defined by prohibiting certain options from the Lexical representation (§3.2.3.1). Specifically, the preceding optional "+" sign is prohibited. The decimal point is required. Leading and trailing zeroes are prohibited subject to the following: **there must be at least one digit to the right and to the left of the decimal point which may be a zero.**

So both `.2` and `0.2` are fine, and they're *equivalent*, so it's OK that protégé normalizes the first as the second.

Comment: I uploaded the generates triples to fuseki and i did this filter `filter (?ratingValue > "0.7"^^xsd:float)` and it works though the data is stored as `.8` not as `0.8` so i have a practical proof now, and thanks for the answer, it gives a clear evidence

Comment: @Ania the point is that they are the *same* value.  Just different printed representations of the same value.